# Best way to loop over the value of a pgfkey key that is a csv list?

Tags: foreach, pgfkeys, pgffor

Using [pgfkeys](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf), suppose that I have a key whose value is a comma separated list:

```
\pgfkeys{/a list/.initial = {1,2,3}}
```

**Question** What is the correct way to iterate over this list using `\foreach` (from [pgffor](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf))?

The only way that I have found that works is to forcibly extract and expand the key value with something like:

```
\edef\alist{\pgfkeysvalueof{/a list}}
\foreach \a in \alist {A = \a\newline}% works!
```

This works but is ungainly as it shouldn't be necessary to extract the value of a key into a temporary variable in order to use it. My initial thought/hope was that something like

```
\foreach \a in \pgfkeysvalueof{/a list} {a = \a\newline}
```

would work, but this gives an error (`! Argument of \pgfkeysvalueof has an extra }.`)

Is there an "officially sanctioned" pgf approach for looping over a comma separated list that is the value of a pgf key? I initially got excited when I found the `.list` handler. It is not unlikely that `.list` does give a way of doing what I want but for the life of me I can't figure how to use it!

**Bonus question** Give an example showing what the `.list` handler does.

Here is full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys,pgffor}

\pgfkeys{/a list/.initial = {1,2,3}}

\begin{document}

    \edef\alist{\pgfkeysvalueof{/a list}}
    \foreach \a in \alist {A = \a\newline}% ugly, but works!

    %\foreach \a in \pgfkeysvalueof{/a list} {a = \a}% does not work

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two solutions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\pgfkeys{
  /list1/.initial = {1,2,3},
  %
  /list2/.store in=\mylisttwo,
  /list2={1,2,3},
}

\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{body loop/.code={A = #1\par},body loop/.list/.expanded=\pgfkeysvalueof{/list1}}

\pgfkeys{/list1={a,b,c}}
\pgfkeys{body loop/.code={A = #1\par},body loop/.list/.expanded=\pgfkeysvalueof{/list1}}

\foreach \b in \mylisttwo {B = \b\par}
\pgfkeys{/list2={a,b,c}}
\foreach \b in \mylisttwo {B = \b\par}

\end{document}
```

To simplify usage, I define a generic style `apply to key`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\pgfkeys{
  apply to key/.style n args={2}{@body loop/.code={#1},@body loop/.list/.expanded=\pgfkeysvalueof{#2}},
  /list1/.initial = {1,2,3},
}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{apply to key={AA = #1\par}{/list1}}
\pgfkeys{/list1={a,b,c}}
\pgfkeys{apply to key={AA = #1\par}{/list1}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Paul! How does the `list1` solution work when I change the value of `list1`? I tried `\pgfkeys{/list1={a,b,c}}\pgfkeys{body loop}` but this did not work
. 

[Your `list2` solution is similar to the `\edef` solution in the question and, like it, this approach suffers from the problem that it creates an external variable `\mylisttwo` outside of pgfkeys...I know that I am idiosyncratic, but I prefer to keep the data inside the pgfkeys...]

Comment: @Andrew  I updated my code to add examples.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I'm afraid that this is less elegant than the solution that I posted.

Comment: @Andrew My `apply to key` solution is generic (you can apply it on any key, list of values or simple value) and does not suffer from the `\foreach` problem (the body of `\foreach` is an implicit group).

Comment: You're right, it is nice. Perhaps I didn't appreciate it enough. You also give a nice example of using `.list`. I am still surprised that there isn't a more direct way of doing this.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if your application would permit a `listofitems` alternative solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\begin{document}
\setsepchar{,}

\readlist*\alist{1,2,3}

\foreachitem\a\in\alist{A = \a\newline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Steven. I didn't know about thew `listofitems` package.  With `pgffor`, it is possible to do what I want using`\def\alist{1,2,3}\foreach \a in \alist {...}` but I really want to do this using pgfkeys.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `pgf`-style answer along the lines of what I am looking for but it places the `\foreach` loop inside the pgfkeys definition rather than having the loop outside of the key structure:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys,pgffor}

\pgfkeys{/mykeys/.is family,/mykeys}
\newcommand\MyKey[1]{\pgfkeys{/mykeys, #1}}
\MyKey{list/.style={llist/.code={\foreach \a in {#1}{A=\a\newline}}}}
\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

  \MyKey{list={1,2,3}}
  \MyKey{llist}

  \MyKey{list={a,b,c}}
  \MyKey{llist}

\end{document}
```

I'd prefer a solution that allows me to loop over the key value outside of the pgfkeys definition and that does not require a "helper" key, like `llist` above.