# multi-striped nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops, parsing

I'm trying to create a `pgf` key that will achieve multicolored nodes with left-to-right stripes using the method outlined [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368908/tikz-only-fill-75-of-the-node-background-with-color/).

However, I would like to provide a more convenient usage for this, perhaps like this:

```
\node[colorstripes={.3:yellow,.5:red,1.:blue}]{hello world};
```

which should color the left 30% of the node yellow, the next 20% red, and the right half blue.

For this, I'm trying to employ the strategy outlined [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351835/best-way-to-loop-over-the-value-of-a-pgfkey-key-that-is-a-csv-list) to loop over values of a `pgf` key. However, I don't really get very far with that. Here's what I am trying so far:

```
\pgfkeys{
  apply to key/.style n args={2}{@body loop/.code={#1},@body loop/.list/.expanded=\pgfkeysvalueof{#2}},
  colorstripes/.initial = {},
}
\pgfkeys{
  apply to key={%
    ($(path picture bounding box.north west)!#1!(path picture bounding box.south west)$)
    rectangle
    ($(path picture bounding box.north east)!#1!(path picture bounding box.south east)$);
  }{colorstripes}}
}
```

However, I don't yet know how to split the argument `#1` into the "width" and the "color" part, and I will also need to access the "last" item to calculate actual the width of the stripe. And even now TikZ doesn't like my code, as it complains about an `Extra }`, so I clearly don't understand what I'm doing here.

Any suggestion, explanation or ready-made solution would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\def\atchar{@}
\tikzset{%
    background stripes/.style={%
        path picture={%
          \pgfnodealias{@}{path picture bounding box}%
          \tikzset{.. background stripes={0|#1,@:@,;}}%
        }
    },
    .. background stripes/.code args={#1|#2:#3,#4;}{%
      \def\tmp{#2}%
      \ifx\tmp\atchar%
      \else%
        \fill [#3] ($(@.north west)!#1!(@.south west)$)
          rectangle ($(@.north east)!#1+#2!(@.south east)$);
        \tikzset{.. background stripes={#1+#2|#4;}}%
      \fi%
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw, align=center, background stripes={
    .20:red, .30:yellow, .10:pink, .05: green, .05:orange, .20:purple, .10:blue
  }] { Some text \\ with a \\ stripy \\ background };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great! I hadn't realised that you could "subvert" styles like this. Really nice!

Comment: It runs faster if you define a helper command for ".. background". The call to \tikzset is *very* slow and does exactly the same thing, for no change in programmer effort. Of course, the difference won't come up unless you use this a lot in the same document, but things like this can really add up.